# Ansatz printing in Qiskit draws a single block

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms, quantum-circuit

When I try to draw the quantum circuit it is shown in only one block and not the whole circuit. For example using the code:

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import RealAmplitudes
ansatz = RealAmplitudes(3, reps=2)
print(ansatz)
```

This code only shows the circuit as one block as follows:

```
     ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
q_0: ┤0                                                              ├
     │                                                               │
q_1: ┤1 RealAmplitudes(θ[0],θ[1],θ[2],θ[3],θ[4],θ[5],θ[6],θ[7],θ[8]) ├
     │                                                               │
q_2: ┤2                                                              ├
     └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Do you know how to show the whole circuit with the details of the gates instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can break all the blocks in a circuit in smaller blocks by using the [`decompose` method](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.decompose.html).

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import RealAmplitudes
ansatz = RealAmplitudes(3, reps=2)
ansatz.decompose().draw('mpl')
```

[image: RealAmplitudes(3, reps=2) decomposition]

Comment: Works great. Thanks alot.